# TFS2012 VSO Hybrid Build Service "Pending"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I need to create an on-prem build agent that pulls its source code from Visual Studio Online. I found a great blog post that describes how to do this here: [blog post](http://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-create-a-hybrid-on-premise-cloud-tfs-2012-build-server/)

My problem is, after following the steps my build service shows it's at a state of "Pending" rather than "Started" and I don't get to see the controller or agents in the TFS admin console as shown below:

[image]

I don't have a full on-prem TFS installation - I just have the newly installed build components.

I see the following error in the event log after 15 minutes:

> Exception Message: The http request operation timed out after 00:15:00. (type TimeoutException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.StartOperation.End(IAsyncResult result, HttpRouter& router, TfsMessageQueue& messageQueue, List`1& processHosts, MachineLifecycleActivity& traceActivity)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.EndStart(IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Machine.WindowsService.EndStartMachine(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: 1). If you click Events 19 information in the last 24 hours, will you find any error message in the Event logs? 2). How about you click Unregister and then register again? 3). Can you start the "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host" service manually in Services? 4). Be sure that the 9191 port is not blocked by firewall setting.

Comment: Is there some reason that you are using the old xaml build agent rather than the new task based agent?

Comment: Thanks for your response Vicky - here are my answers 1) When I looked yesterday, the events were only "service started / stopped". However ther are error message this morning - I will as to the main question. 2) Unregister / register does not help 3) Yes 4) Port 9191 is no blocked

Comment: I am using the xaml build because I will need to make use of some custom xaml build templates

Comment: I'd recommend moving forward to a newer build agent - TFS 2013 Update 5 or TFS 2015 build agent. I don't know for sure that it will solve your problem, but the 2012 build agent is rather old at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this problem was firewall related but nothing to do with port 9191. I think only port 443 is used. The problem seemed to relate to the fact that I had a domain account for the build service but need to use my hotmail account for the service to authenticate with visual studio online to pull down the source code. The build service was able to cope with this ok but the internet proxy service that "protected" the client's network needed additional configuration

Although that was the cause of the problem, whilst attempting a fix, I moved to using a TFS2015 build agent as Buck suggested. I downloaded the agent from the visual studio online site. I am now using the new web based build designer rather than xaml and I have found it to be excellent and it builds BizTalk solutions just fine - thanks for the advice Buck :)